# WebGL intregation disable input field

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, input, unity-webgl, disable

I'm currently developing a chatbot interface in HTML which includes a 3d character builds in WebGL `c#`.

To interact with our AI platform we have a chatbox which is an input field where the user writes his question and send it by clicking on a button or by pressing enter key.

The problem is that it is impossible to write any text in that field. It seems to be `desactivated` when I integrate the WebGL content. In order to be able to send text, I have to go through the Chrome Developers Tool and write into the element in question.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have the eventsystem in?

Comment: This has to be set on the unity side ?

Comment: when you add a UI its added automatically, the eventsystem makes the UI work

Comment: Thank you. I finally found this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897929/unity-webgl-prevent-canvas-from-eating-up-all-mouse-keyboard-input-html?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897929/unity-webgl-prevent-canvas-from-eating-up-all-mouse-keyboard-input-html?rq=1)

Comment: Odd, ive not suffered from my text entry boxes ever needing that

Comment: Adding this simple line in the MonoBehaviour class works for me 

<!-- language: c# -->
WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput = false;

The canvas was focusing all the inputs.